# Target not Found: Not Able to Install Packages in Arch Linux

Tags: docker, archlinux

I tried to install several packages on Arch Linux on Docker. Here is the steps:

```
docker run -it --rm archlinux
pacman -Syu --noconfirm
pacman -S bwidget
```

All I got is

```
[root@d2102c694f15 /]# pacman -S bwidget
error: target not found: bwidget
```

Although, I can see that `bwidget` is available in Arch Linux repository (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bwidget/).

This happens also for other packages like `udunits`, `jags`, `v8`, and some others.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, I thought https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bwidget/ is the official repository. It is not.
To install from https://aur.archlinux.org/, one needs to do the steps written in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_packages